# How can stuck effect at 1.0 zoom scale be achieved?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

How can stuck effect at 1.0 zoom scale be achieved?

I want to help my app's users to determine when are they viewing the content in 1.0 zoomScale.

To achieve this I would like to automatically set the UIScrollView's zoomScale to 1.0 when the current zoomScale is around 1.0 (eg.: between 0.75 and 1.25).

(Of course, after the mentioned auto-zoomScale-setting, I still want my UIScrollView's zoomScale to be able to set to any zoomScale between it's minimumZoomScale and maximumZoomScale.)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using the pinchGestureRecognizer's velocity. this way it will "stick" at 1.0 unless the user zooms "harder". Maybe something like this will work for you:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (scrollView.zoomScale >= 0.75 && scrollView.zoomScale <= 1.25) {
        if (fabs(scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer.velocity) < velocityTolerance) {
            scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;
        }
    }
}
```

I found that I needed to adjust this slightly to have a different tolerance for zooming in than for zooming out. Maybe start with 5.0 as a tolerance and see how that feels.

Comment: Yes-yes. I haven't mentioned, but I've already tried something similar. My only problem with this is that around 1.0 zoom level, when I try to pinch in or out, the zoomed view is "shaking" as long as I don't reach the zoom level that is smaller than 0.75 or larger than 1.25. Do you know how can it be fixed? Thanks in advance for your answer!